# Postman 401 getting unauthorized (SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing a api hit to register users to a database. But when I call the api, it's showing a 401 unauthorized error in postman. As of right now, i'm just using basic auth and will later implement JWT authorization. Can someone help me?

Controller Class:

```
import com.insta.backend.exceptions.UserException;
import com.insta.backend.model.User;
import com.insta.backend.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class AuthController {
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;

    public AuthController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<User> registerUserHandler(@RequestBody User user) throws UserException {
        User createdUser = userService.registerUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(createdUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UserService class:

```
public interface UserService{
    
    public User registerUser(User user) throws UserException;
    public User findUserById(Integer userId) throws UserException;
    public User findUserByProfile(String token) throws UserException;
    public User findUserByUserName(String userName) throws UserException;
    public String followUser(Integer reqUserId,Integer followUserId) throws UserException;
    public String unFollowUser(Integer reqUserId,Integer followUserId) throws UserException;
    
    public List<User> findUsersByIds(List<Integer> userIds) throws UserException;
    
    public List<User> searchUser(String query) throws UserException; //api for searching users
    public User updateUserDetails(User updatedUser,User existingUser) throws UserException; //api for updating users
    
    
    

}
```

UserServiceImpl class:

```
import com.insta.backend.dto.UserDto;
import com.insta.backend.exceptions.UserException;
import com.insta.backend.model.User;
import com.insta.backend.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.parameters.P;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.swing.text.html.Option;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserServiceImplementation implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @Override
    public User registerUser(User user) throws UserException {
        Optional<User> doesEmailExist = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        if(doesEmailExist.isPresent()){
            throw new UserException("Email is already in use!!");
        }
        Optional<User> doesUserNameExist = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUserName());

        if(doesEmailExist.isPresent()){
            throw new UserException("Username is already taken!!");
        }
        if(user.getUserName()==null || user.getEmail()==null||user.getPassword()==null|| user.getRealName()==null){
            throw new UserException("All fields are mandatory");
        }
        User newUser = new User(); 
        newUser.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        newUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        newUser.setUserName(user.getUserName());
        newUser.setRealName(user.getRealName());
        return userRepository.save(newUser);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserById(Integer userId) throws UserException {
        Optional<User> optUser= userRepository.findById(userId);
        if(optUser.isPresent()){
            return optUser.get();
        }
        throw new UserException("User does not exist with the following id:"+userId);
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByProfile(String token) throws UserException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public User findUserByUserName(String userName) throws UserException {
        Optional<User> user=userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
        if(user.isPresent()){
            return user.get();
        }
        throw new UserException("User with the inputted username doesn't exist"+userName);
    }

    @Override
    public String followUser(Integer reqUserId, Integer followUserId) throws UserException {
       
       User reqUser = findUserById(reqUserId);
       User followUser = findUserById(followUserId);

        UserDto follower = new UserDto();
        follower.setEmail(reqUser.getEmail());
        follower.setId(reqUser.getId());
        follower.setName(reqUser.getRealName());
        follower.setUserImage(reqUser.getImage());
        follower.setUsername(reqUser.getUserName());
        
        UserDto following = new UserDto();
        following.setEmail(follower.getEmail());       
        following.setUsername(follower.getUsername());       
        following.setId(follower.getId());       
        following.setName(follower.getName());       
        following.setUserImage(follower.getUserImage());       
        
        reqUser.getFollowing().add(following);
        followUser.getFollower().add(follower);
        
        userRepository.save(followUser);
        userRepository.save(reqUser);
        
        
        return "You are following :"+followUser.getUserName();
    }

    @Override
    public String unFollowUser(Integer reqUserId, Integer followUserId) throws UserException {

        User reqUser = findUserById(reqUserId);
        User followUser = findUserById(followUserId);

        UserDto follower = new UserDto();
        follower.setEmail(reqUser.getEmail());
        follower.setId(reqUser.getId());
        follower.setName(reqUser.getRealName());
        follower.setUserImage(reqUser.getImage());
        follower.setUsername(reqUser.getUserName());

        UserDto following = new UserDto();
        following.setEmail(follower.getEmail());
        following.setUsername(follower.getUsername());
        following.setId(follower.getId());
        following.setName(follower.getName());
        following.setUserImage(follower.getUserImage());

        reqUser.getFollowing().remove(following);
        followUser.getFollower().remove(follower);

        userRepository.save(followUser);
        userRepository.save(reqUser);


        return "You just unfollowed :"+followUser.getUserName();
        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findUsersByIds(List<Integer> userIds) throws UserException {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAllUsersByUserIds(userIds);
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> searchUser(String query) throws UserException {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByQuery(query);
        if(users.size()==0){
            throw new UserException("No users retrieved!");
        }
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public User updateUserDetails(User updatedUser, User existingUser) throws UserException {
        if(updatedUser.getEmail()!=null){
            existingUser.setEmail(updatedUser.getEmail());
        }

        if(updatedUser.getBio()!=null){
            existingUser.setBio(updatedUser.getBio());
        }
        if(updatedUser.getRealName()!=null){
            existingUser.setRealName(updatedUser.getRealName());
        }
        if(updatedUser.getUserName()!=null){
            existingUser.setUserName(updatedUser.getUserName());
        }
        if(updatedUser.getMobile()!=null){
            existingUser.setMobile(updatedUser.getMobile());
        }
        if(updatedUser.getGender()!=null){
            existingUser.setGender(updatedUser.getBio());
        }
        
        if(updatedUser.getWebsite()!=null){
            existingUser.setWebsite(updatedUser.getWebsite());
        }
        
        if(updatedUser.getImage()!=null){
            existingUser.setImage(updatedUser.getImage());
        }
        
        if(updatedUser.getId().equals(existingUser.getId())){
            return userRepository.save(existingUser);
        }
        
        
        
         throw new UserException("You can't update this user");
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityConfiguration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                // ...
                .csrf((csrf)->csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth)->auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
//                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenGenerator(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) //generates json token after validation of whatever request api is coming
//                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenValidation(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) // validates the request api before sending it into the application
              
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .build();



    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8090

spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/insta_clone

spirng.jpa.generate-ddl=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.security.user.name=******
spring.security.user.password=********

logging.level.guru.sfg.brewery=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug
```

error:
[image]

authorization in postman:
[image]

** Note: Even before and  after disabling for test purposes, I'm still getting an invalid CSRF token error in the output terminal when I debug the application **

Debug Log:
[image]

Comment: try http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

Comment: Also click on `Authorization` button on postman and provide a image of what you are sending as credentials

Comment: im guessing what you are suggesting is a deprecated method and for the authorization part i chose basic auth and gave username and password as what i mentioned in the application.properties file

Comment: and i have added the authorization ss in the post for your reference, thanks for the advice

Comment: This api has permitAll permission right? can u try `no auth` in postman?

Comment: yes it does have permitAll and i tried with no auth,still no luck :(

Comment: May i ask the reason for why you havnt looked up how to enable spring security debug logs and read the actual reason for the 401, before you decided to ask here?

Comment: wdym? @Toerktumlare

Comment: that if you just enable spring security debug logs you can just read the reason as to why you are getting a 401. Why havnt you done that? instead of everyone here just trying to guess what is wrong with your code. And if you dont understand what it says in the logs you edit your question and include your logs in your question and ask about that instead?

Comment: lmao my bad i added the debug log,its saying a csrf invalid token but idk what to do about it